# Maven - display-dependency-updates- list transitive dependency versions

Tags: java, maven, maven-versions-plugin

I'd like to be able to see if any of the dependencies of my project - including transitive ones - have updates available.

Take the following `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run goal `versions:display-dependency-updates` I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------< org.me:test >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:display-dependency-updates (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] No dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions.
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.939 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-12T17:09:39Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run `dependency:tree`, I can now see:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] org.me:test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
```

And an outdated version of `log4j` appears.

Is there a way of doing this that's not manual?

I've also tried `dependency-updates-report` with the `processDependencyManagementTransitive` option enabled (which is the default) and the transitive dependencies aren't listed.

Comment: Feels weird. Has it not been omitted from the report for some reason? Have you also tried "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose"?

Comment: `versions:display-dependency-updates` will only report on direct dependencies but not on transitive dependencies. The outdates dependency is a dependency of poi...You can simple define the newer version directly to your own project which will overwrite the old one...

Comment: @khmarbaise I understand how I could fix this contrived example, but if it was a large enterprise project with many internal dependencies, those versions would be under my responsibility to manage.

Comment: @Eugenio I get the same output with ``-Dverbose``, but I don't think it's a problem with ``dependency:tree`` as it's reporting the situation correctly.

Comment: If those dependencies are under your own control you have to go and start by the transitive dependency and start there with upgrading to the most recent versions one by one... there you can use versions plugin to upgrade and continuing one by one...

Comment: @khmarbaise that was the manual process I wanted to avoid.

Comment: I wrote `use versions plugin`... you should check what I have wrote... check this: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html

Comment: @khmarbaise does that list transitive dependencies? If so do you have an example?

Comment: What is the point to know a transitive dependency has updates if the parent dependency has not been released with the latest version? e.g. if org.apache.poi:poi:jar does not uses yet the latest org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar (e.g. 2.17.1). You can also have more recent releases like major version upgrade but not compatible with your 1st level deps.

Comment: @рüффп see my previous comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685712/maven-display-dependency-updates-list-transitive-dependency-versions?noredirect=1#comment124962332_70685712 - those dependencies are under my control.